# Changing text color with new command in .cls file

Tags: macros, color, section-titles

I'm writing a class which I can call `myclass`. I try to define the following commands for changing the text colors (text, section, etc.):

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\setsectioncolor}[1]{\color[#1]}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}{}

\newcommand{\setsubsectioncolor}[1]{\color{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsectioncolor}{}

\newcommand{\setsubsubsectioncolor}[1]{\color{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsubsectioncolor}{}

\newcommand{\settxtcolor}[1]{\color{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtcolor}{}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to define `\sectcolor`, etc. and could really use some help. I will try to explain what I want to do with these commands.

I would like to redefine section, etc. using `\sectcolor`:

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\headingfont\Large\bfseries\sectioncolor}}
```

Comment: Options to classes should be passed in squared brackets: `\documentclass[]{}`

Comment: How does `myclass` define `\section` and `\subsection`? For the `set` commands you probably want something like `\colorlet{sectcol}{#1}` rather than a macro `\sectcol` although it isn't very clear how you're planning to use things.

Comment: @cfr I edited the question.

Comment: @Vebjorn: You seem to need the following definition of `\setsectioncolor`: `\newcommand{\setsectioncolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\sectioncolor}{\color{#1}}}`. And your (re)definition of `\section` with `\sectioncolor` should then work as expected (assuming you've also defined `\headingfont` as well which, by the way, should probably *follow* `\Large\bfseries` so that `\headingfont` would add to the default style).

Comment: Thanks @Werner. I think you should make it an answer to the question. It was very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation that allows you to adjust the colour of the sectional units. Additional `\resetXcolor` macros are provided to remove any previous colour definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\setsectioncolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\sectioncolor}{\color{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}{}% Default is no colour
\newcommand{\resetsectioncolor}{\renewcommand{\sectioncolor}{}}% Restore (default) section colour

\newcommand{\setsubsectioncolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\subsectioncolor}{\color{#1}}}
\newcommand{\subsectioncolor}{}% Default is no colour
\newcommand{\resetsubsectioncolor}{\renewcommand{\subsectioncolor}{}}% Restore (default) subsection colour

\newcommand{\setsubsubsectioncolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\subsubsectioncolor}{\color{#1}}}
\newcommand{\subsubsectioncolor}{}% Default is no colour
\newcommand{\resetsubsubsectioncolor}{\renewcommand{\subsubsectioncolor}{}}% Restore (default) subsection colour

\makeatletter
% Taken from https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sectioncolor}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                       {\normalfont\large\bfseries\subsectioncolor}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\subsubsectioncolor}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setsectioncolor{red}
\section{A red section}

\setsubsectioncolor{green}
\subsection{A green subsection}

\setsubsubsectioncolor{blue}
\subsubsection{A blue subsubsection}

\resetsectioncolor
\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

Note that [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) already provides a similar setup:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,sectsty}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\section{A red section}

\subsectionfont{\color{green}}
\subsection{A green subsection}

\subsubsectionfont{\color{blue}}
\subsubsection{A blue subsubsection}

\sectionfont{\color{black}}
\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass the color model to the tag `\sectioncolor`, modified `MWE` given below:

```
\documentclass{book}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\setsectioncolor}[1]{\color[#1]}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}{\color{cyan}}

\newcommand{\setsubsectioncolor}[1]{\color{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsectioncolor}{}

\newcommand{\setsubsubsectioncolor}[1]{\color{#1}}
\newcommand{\subsubsectioncolor}{}

\newcommand{\settxtcolor}[1]{\color{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtcolor}{}

\newcommand{\headingfont}{\Large\bfseries}%

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\headingfont\sectioncolor}}
\makeatother

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

I have defined a new tag `\headingfont` and placed the `\Large\bfseries` into the tag, so it is easy if you want to change font style for `\section`...

Comment: Why do you define a default colour for `\section`s to be `cyan`? Also, have you tried changing it to something else via `\setsectioncolor{<colour>}`?

Comment: Also, I swapped `\normalfont` with `\headingfont` to make a command `\setheadingfont` that enables you to change the font. \rmfamily, \ttfamily, etc.